# Getting country boundaries

Tags: actionscript-3, google-maps, maps, png

I have this map

[image]

I managed to extract each country in different png file and I made this map by using AS3 code to place each country in its own place. It works properly but there is one thing I don't like and that is the quality of the images. You clearly see gaps between some countries and some borders are thicker than others. That is because I did the extraction with free hand.

Is there a way to get more clear boundaries with code and export the result in png file for each country?

Maybe using some map services like Google maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to use vector images instead; you can find some in the SVG format (easily convertible) on Wikipedia:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b3/Blank_map_of_Europe.svg

Each `<path></path>` node in the file refers to a country, where the `id` attribute contains the country code and the `d` attribute is the path in the SVG format.

Comment: From the description of the map:
"A blank Map of Europe. Every country has an id which is its `ISO-3166-1-ALPHA2` code in lower case."

This seems to be exactly what you need, a map with individual country elements in a file format that "just works".

Comment: In addition to the question here is a link with all vector maps from wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Blank_maps